# How to use wireshark dissectors in own application without wireshark at all?

Tags: wireshark, libpcap

Im using libpcap and want to be able to analyze packets but without wireshark at all. However, I want to use the wireshark dissectors. Has anybody done this and can give me an explanation for the needed steps?

Comment: Wireshark has been ported to android by the nexmon project: www.nexmon.org

Answer (score 1):

First of all see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308127/using-libwireshark-to-get-wireshark-functionality-programatically) about the dangers of using `epan` and linking to `libwireshark`.  You're basically alone trying to make it work, it is not meant to work that way and a new version may break your code.  It is always suggested to [write a dissector instead](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/ChapterDissection.html) since that API is not going to change.

---

If that did not scare you please read forward.

I have not performed it but i'm more-or-less familiar with the `wireshark` code tree.  I believe that what you're after is the `#include <epan/packet.h>`, `#include <epan/frame_data.h>` and `#include <epan/tvbuff.h>` (Testy Virtual Buffer), these header files are distributed together with `wireshark` since are needed to write plugin dissectors.

Since one protocol often contains another protocol as the payload `wireshark`'s way to deal with is the `tvbuff_t`.  One dissector returns a `tvbuff_t` which can then be used by another dissector.  You need to perform the entire decoding of the packet, (for example, starting from Ethernet) since `wireshark` is not there to do it for you.

The code in the [`epan` directory](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=tree;f=epan;h=b221e7e1de73bd7440a15c015935cb0355300612;hb=HEAD) is documented in the [`doc` directory](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=tree;f=doc;h=881e8185e7d3d6884a8eecd5accf0ce448aaf499;hb=HEAD), notably the [section 1.7 of `doc/README.dissectors` (Calling Other Dissectors)](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob;f=doc/README.dissector;h=7e41cc4b74fba917fecad9564a93acd436e98006;hb=HEAD) has information on how to use `tvbuff_t` and `find_dissector()`.

It is a very hacky way of doing things, therefore i'll warn again: if you can get away with writing a dissector and use it within `wireshark`, do it.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following Project on Github:

https://github.com/gnychis/android-wmon

One has to do some modifications in order to get it work, but much much easier than starting from the beginning.

Comment: That's an interesting project!  I assume you wanted an android focused API in the first place.  I just went quickly through the code and i believe it does not support Ethernet decoding (which isn't a problem at all if you're on a smartphone but might be if you're on a webserver).  I'm just adding the comment in case someone finds this question while searching for a similar solution.

Comment: Can you explain why it doesnt support Ethernet decoding? Which parts are missing?

Comment: First, i need to admit that i never wrote android code therefore i may be very wrong, since i do not know what `android.os.Parcel` does for an example.  But in the [hardware handlers](https://github.com/gnychis/android-wmon/tree/master/application/src/com/gnychis/awmon/HardwareHandlers) there is no Ethernet handlers (which i would expect), and the [LANScanner](https://github.com/gnychis/android-wmon/blob/master/application/src/com/gnychis/awmon/InterfaceScanners/LANScanner.java) has a hardcoded `--interface=wlan0`.  As i said i never wrote android code maybe `wlan0` can be used as ethernet?

Comment: I think the whole project only works fine for the mentioned hardware with external wlan usb card supporting monitor mode. However, I only use the C code on android and only use the dissecting part with the help of wireshark_helper.c. This works great.